# A question about the definition of additive categories.

Tags: category-theory

What does the following line mean

> The composition of morphisms is distributive over addition.

Does it mean $a+(b\circ c)=(a+b)\circ (a+c)$?

Comment: I think $a\circ (b+c)=a \circ b+a\circ c$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_category

Comment: We usually say, for numbers, that multiplication is distributive over addition, which means $a(b+c)=ab+ac$. Besides, if $a+(b\circ c)$ is defined, it may not be the case that $a+b$ or $a+c$ are defined. On the other hand, if $a\circ(b+c)$ is defined, then $a\circ b$ and $a\circ c$ are both defined.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the composition map
$$ \hom(A,B) \times \hom(B,C) \to \hom(A,C),\, (f,g) \mapsto g \circ f $$
is $\mathbb Z$-bilinear for all objects $A,B,C$ in the category. (A more general concept is the one of [*enriched category*](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+category#InMonoidCat) over a monoidal category.)

So it means that $a\circ (b+c) = a \circ b + a \circ c$ and that $(a+b) \circ c = a \circ c + b \circ c$ whenever the compositions make sense.

Comment: The last part of this answer is correct, but the first part is not. A morphism $\circ$ from a direct product of two abelian groups to another abelian group would satisfy $(a+c)\circ(b+d)=(a\circ b)+(c\circ d)$, which is not what you want.

Comment: Should be the tensor product, instead.

Comment: Yes of course, I typed to fast. I edit that. @AndreasBlass

Comment: @JakobWerner But a priori there is no map from the tensor product to $\hom(A,C)$. You need to require that composition is a morphism component-wise to induce a proper arrow $\hom(A,B) \otimes \hom(B,C) \to \hom(A,C)$.

Comment: Yes, but if I define a semiadditice category as a category enriched over the monoidal category of abelian groups, I first have an arrow $\hom\otimes\hom\to\hom $ and then use my knowledge about tensor products of abelian to obtain a map $\hom\times\hom\to\hom $, which gives me the structure of an ordinary category. This is not the procedure of the OP, but the one which is closer to the concept of enriched categories you mentioned.

Comment: @JakobWerner I totally agree but I could not respond to the OP : "it means that $\hom \otimes \hom \to \hom$ is a group morphism", as he/she would ask "what is the map". So in order to answer the question of the OP, I should take the _real composition_ and suppose it is bilinear. That is the difference between *one Ab-enriched structure* and the *property* to be pre-additive.